# Cloud Foundry : Java Build Pack : Opentelemtry Javagent extension integration with jar from a repo

Tags: cloud-foundry, buildpack, open-telemetry-java

With the newly added ability on Java build pack to support monitoring using Opentelemetry javaagent is nice. We have written extensions to this javagent for monitoring our custom libraries - we can make aware of the javagent of these new extension by setting environment variable -Dotel.javagent.extensions refereing to a folder / or a jar locally.

Unfortunately this does not play well when we use Java Build pack (without explicitly having to include the extension as a dependency on your project). Considering we have a huge number of endstates that we want to add this instrumentation - is there a way to pull these extensions from an http instead of a local folder ? This mechansim am thinking of is very similiar to newrelic agent support which lets us to add extensions from http addresses by setting JBP_CONFIG_NEW_RELIC_AGENT property

Answer (score 0):

> is there a way to pull these extensions from an http instead of a local folder ?

The support in the buildpack is only going to pull in the open telemetry JAR from [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation/cloudfoundry/index.yml).

If you just need to add a few additional class files, you could possibly repackage them within the Open Telemetry JAR itself. The buildpack will only download a single JAR, but you can tell it to pull the JAR from somewhere else.

You'd need to host the modified JAR and the index.yml I linked to above somewhere else. Then you can use [operator level config](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack/tree/main?tab=readme-ov-file#operator) to override the location of that file for all apps. I believe the env variable to set would be `JBP_CONFIG_OPEN_TELEMETRY_JAVAAGENT` and you'd want to set it to `{repository_root: "https://your-server.example.com/path/to/folder/with/index_yaml/"}`. That should change the location from which it loads the JARs and it should load your modified JAR.

> This mechansim am thinking of is very similiar to newrelic agent support which lets us to add extensions from http addresses by setting JBP_CONFIG_NEW_RELIC_AGENT property

The OpenTelemetry support in the CF Java buildpack does not support extensions like New Relic. It seems like a reasonable idea though, so feel free to open an issue and request it. https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack/issues

---

The other option would be to create a custom buildpack that installs your additional files and use multi-buildpack support to have that buildpack run first, then have the Java buildpack run. The Java buildpack has to run last though, that's a requirement of the CF JBP.

https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/use-multiple-buildpacks.html

I'm not sure this will totally solve your issue though because you still have to remember to have the buildpacks run in that order.